# Is supreme brahman male or female? Does He have a gender?

Tags: scripture

Is supreme brahman male or female?

Does he have a gender?

EDIT: Soul or jivatma is different from brahman who is the paramatma. Hence this question is different.

Comment: He has no gender. But he is called "Purusha", which doesn't actually mean biological male, but rather that he is the lord of the Jivas who are all "women", since they are dependent on him.

Comment: I think this is the same question? https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23699/does-a-soul-have-any-gender

Comment: No, Atman (whether you consider Jivatma or Paramatma) doesn't have any gender, Visit [Does a soul have any gender?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/23699/277).

Comment: @Ikshvaku "Jivas are woman" is that about gender?

Comment: lord is mother because he bore in his womb all the universe he is father because he gave the names to different gods he created. he is both one who thus will reach heavenly status. As per hindus god is not physical he is chinmayananda or sat chit ananda or gnananda roopa intelligence and pleasure are his form

Comment: @Pandya No, Jivas are "women", in the sense that they are subservient to Brahman who is the "Purusha", like how wives obey their husbands today.